# rtcwake from acpi state s5

Tags: 12.04

I've used `rtcwake` on my desktop for some time running Precise Pangolin without problems. Recently I came across a thinkpad x230 with an ultradock which I also installed Precise Pangolin on.

It works great and for a while `rtcwake` seemed to work as well. I noticed that it only seemed to support "off-mode" when attached to the dock though. Now it no longer seems to support "off-mode" and that's my problem. It doesn't wake up no more. I've tried "mem" and that works, but I really would like "off" to work as well.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Update: It seems that rtcwake only works as long as the computer is not fully shut down. If powered off or if using "shutdown" via terminal it seems the previously set wake up time won't work no matter which "mode" was being used when setting it. I've tried to set rtcwake with "mem" mode after which the system hibernates, then resuming the system, powering off, resuming again and finally hibernating it. Then when the set wake up time arrives nothing happens. So it seems powering off the system will hinder rtcwake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was a BIOS issue. Changing various BIOS settings seems to have solved the problem. Likely it was me changing the value of "Wake on AC" to disabled which caused the problem in the first case. For future reference the problem seems to have been the value of "Alarm_irq" being changed to "no" instead of the "yes" it should have been, during shutdown or restart.